# generate ros2 interfaces (messages, services) directly in Python?

Tags: python, ros2

Is there a way to create ros2 interfaces (messages, services) directly from Python, without going through translating .msg and .srv files?

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you shouldn't. When ROS message, service, and action files are built they are simply turned into a class. When creating a publisher it is simply expecting a reference to a class. Take the following example:

```
from rclpy.node import Node

class SomeMessage:
    some_field = 1
    other_field = 2

basic_node = Node('some_node')
basic_node.create_publisher(SomeMessage, '/some_topic')
```

This is perfectly valid and you can publish messages like this. The main issue is that this message definition is local to the script you create it in. Any subscriber would have to either reach out and import from this script, or redefine the message.